# Upgrade python version in AWS Apache Airflow (MWAA)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I am working with Apache Airflow in AWS (MWAA) and I have deployed a python package that was developed on python 3.8. It was running fine locally, however, on MWAA it starts giving syntax errors probably because the python version in MWAA is 3.7. Is there any possibility to upgrade the python version in MWAA or any workaround for this?

Comment: Can you share the syntax error you were having?

Answer (score 2):

MWAA with certain airflow versions now supports newer python versions. For example, version 2.4.3 uses 3.10: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-faqs.html#python-version).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-faqs.html#python-version **MWAA uses python 3.7**

It means `plugins` and `DAGs` will have to be in python 3.7 (no walrus for you!)
But `tasks` can still be run on python 3.8+ if:

- you run them in docker (via EC2, Sagemaker or other)
- you upgrade python on a worker using the bashOperator (I do not recommand it)

I hope they upgrade soon.